# Output from for loop in LaTeX table

Tags: tables, r

I have a for loop in an R file and I need the output of for loop to be stored in a table for LaTeX. I know about the table package, but I can't figure it out. My code goes as follows:

```
for(i in seq(2000,2016, by=1)) {
  cat("In year ",i, "the mortality rate for males is",greece$rate$male[i])
}
for(i in seq(1999,2015,by=1)) {
```

Comment: When you might be so inclined, the [datatool package](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool?lang=en) could likely resolve this problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xtable`:

```
library(xtable)

M <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(1999:2015), ncol = 2)
ict <- 1
for(i in seq(1999,2015,by=1)) {
 M[ict,1] <-  i
 M[ict,2] <- runif(1)
 ict <- ict + 1
}

xtable(M)
```

And you can also write `seq(1999,2015,by=1)` as `1999:2015`

Comment: That works perfectly with my code `M <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(1999:2015), ncol = 2)
ict <- 1
for(i in seq(1999,2015,by=1)) {
  M[ict,1] <-   i
  M[ict,2] <- round(greece$rate$male[i],8)
  ict <- ict + 1
}` but when i run `xtable(M)` i get zeros at the second column althoug the matrix M contains all my data

Comment: fixed it. It needs `xtable(M, digits=4)`